# Merge Sort in C

Tags: beginner, c, sorting, mergesort

I implemented mergesort in C as an exercise. I have two main questions:

2. Is the code future-proof?

   2.1 Will I have problems modifying it to sort float and double?

   2.2 What could be problematic for creating a multithreaded version? I haven't learned multithreading in C yet, but I plan on a multithreaded version later on.

Secondary question:

3. What could I change in the code to make it better?

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void join (int* array, int* array_left, int* array_right, size_t len, size_t len_left)
{
    size_t counter_left = 0;
    size_t counter_right = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (counter_right == len - len_left || counter_left < len_left && array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right])
        {
            array[i] = array_left[counter_left];
            counter_left++;            
        }
        else
        {
            array[i] = array_right[counter_right];
            counter_right++;
        }
    }

    return;
}

void partition (int* array, int* array_part, size_t start_p, size_t len_p)
{
    for (size_t i = start_p; i < len_p; i++)
    {
        array_part[i-start_p] = array[i];
    }

    return;
}

void mergesort(int* array, size_t len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return;
    }

    size_t len2 = len / 2;

    int array_left[len2];
    int array_right[len-len2];

    //Partitioning array into left and right
    partition (array, array_left, 0, len2);
    partition (array, array_right, len2, len);

    //recursiv call
    mergesort(array_left, len2);
    mergesort(array_right, len - len2);

    //joining / sorting of the partitions
    join(array, array_left, array_right, len, len2);

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,7,8,9,6,5,4,0};        
    size_t len = sizeof array / sizeof array[0];

    printf("Array unsorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    mergesort(array, len);

    printf("Array sorted: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is merge sort, so I suggest removing question 1. after my edit is reviewed.

Comment: Best to avoid mixing sign-ness of integers as in `i < len` or `for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)`, even in test code.

Answer (score 2):

- The condition `counter_right == len - len_left || counter_left < len_left && array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right])` looks scary. You'd be in much better shape separating `join` into two phases: actual merge, and handling tails:

  ```
  void join (int* array, int* array_left, int* array_right, size_t len, size_t len_left)
  {
      size_t counter_left = 0;
      size_t counter_right = 0;
      size_t i;

      // Phase 1: merge
      while (counter_left < len_left && counter_right < len - len_left) {
          if (array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right]) {
              array[i++] = array_left[counter_left++];
          } else {
              array[i++] = array_right[counter_right++];
          }
      }

      // Phase 2: tails
      // Now one of the arrays is exhausted. Another one (possibly) still
      // has data. Copy them to the target array.
      // Notice that we don't care which one is empty: copying from an empty
      // array is no-op.
      while (counter_left < len_left) {
          array[i++] = array_left[counter_left++];
      }

      while (counter_right < len - len_left) {
          array[i++] = array_right[counter_right++];
      }
  }
  ```
- Of course, the two tail loops above implement a `copy` algorithm, and deserve to be factored out into a function. Interestingly, you already have this function. You just misnamed it. `partition` is actually `copy`.

  In fact, you may consider dropping altogether, and use `memcpy` instead.
- Recursion is expensive. For the arrays small enough, insertion sort is faster. Consider switching to insertion sort when `len` is less than a threshold, say `16`. The exact value of the threshold is fine tuning, and requires some profiling experiments.
- Using VLAs is scary. Given a huge array it may overflow the stack. Consider heap allocation. Notice that the scratch array can be allocated only once.
- Kudos for `<=` when comparing elements. Many people miss that this is how mergesort maintains stability.

Comment: What I think is weird is that the `copy` in quicksort also copies the element.

Comment: @vnp First of thanks for your help. I was wondering, if I really need to check for ```counter_right < len - len_left``` in the first while_loop. I thought len_left is always smaller or equal to len - len_left, because ```size_t len2 = len / 2;``` will make sure of that. Or is that depending on the system the code is running on?
And can you tell me, what you mean with scratch array? I tried google, but didn't help.

Comment: Note that `<=` is insufficient to maintain stability with floating point values that include not-a-number.

Answer (score 0):

> 2.1 Will I have problems modifying it to sort `float` and `double`?

The "sort" comes down to one line:

```
array_left[counter_left] <= array_right[counter_right]
```

With floating point, sorting concerns include:

- Signed zeros: -0.0 and +0.0

Typically the solution is to consider these of equal *value*.  So an array of [-0.0, +0.0, -0.0, +0.0 ...], with the code, should produce a stable sort.  If an order is needed (e.g. -0.0 before +0.0) , the compare will need to expand to account for the sign.

- [Not-a-numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN)

When `x` is a NaN, comparing *usually*<sup>1</sup> results in `false` as in `x <= y` and even `x == x`.

With code's singular use of `<=` for comparing, I foresee a problem, perhaps like  [`qsort()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48069404/2410359) which require [total ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order).  A more advanced [compare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48069558/2410359) would be needed to handle arrays which include NaN.

---

<sup>1</sup> C does not specify how compares behave with NaN.  Most systems do follow IEEE of comparing with `<= , <, >, >=, ==` involving at least 1 NaN is *false*.